# Indeterminate state is not obtained in CheckBox with Nullable bool property

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to show the checkbox is loaded with indeterminate state instead of checked/unchecked state.

code snippet,

```
private bool? nullCheck = null;

    public bool? NullCheck
    {
        get { return nullCheck; }
        set { nullCheck = value;  }
    }



 <CheckBox  IsChecked="{x:Bind Path=NullCheck}" IsThreeState="True"/>
```

Then CheckBox is loaded with indeterminate state.

When i set the binding in code behind like below,

```
<CheckBox  Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded" IsThreeState="True"/>
 private void CheckBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = sender as CheckBox;
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("NullCheck");
        uiElement.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
    }
```

Here checkbox IsChecked property returns false instead of null value. I couldnt understand why. any one helps to bind the null value for checkbox in code behind by using SetBinding method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding Null value is not supported in WinRT/UWP. Its ignored by control.

For workaround you can subclass the CheckBox and add the Dependency Property to support nullable binding.

Here is well explained [bind to a nullable type](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html) article wriiten by Jerrynixon related to this issue and solution.

Comment: Thanks :-) I have bound this NullableCheckBox to DataGrid Column's template as explained in http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html . When i trying to sort that column, then checkbox  (null)indeterminate value gets changed to True. I have checked the call stack and found that Native to managed code transition  and vice versa is happening.